# What is the equivalent of (real, unrestricted) drop database in Oracle?

Tags: oracle

Suppose I am connected to Oracle as user foo, using my schema foo (which is how schemas work in Oracle, as far as I can tell). I am testing some scripts and eventually want to start over. Now, in any regular DBMS, I can drop foo, re-create it, and use it, all without disconnecting a session.
Is there an equivalent in Oracle that doesn't involve deleting all objects manually or mucking with users and connections too much? I have admin access to the server in this case but I'm hoping to keep is simple/scriptable w/o disconnecting.

Comment: The only way I could envision something like this working would be to connect to the database as the admin user, not as `foo`, potentially setting the `current_schema` to `foo` for name resolution purposes and, if you want to get really tricky (i.e. dangerous) using `dbms_sys_sql` to run code as `foo`.  That being said, I'm not sure that I see the issue with closing the connection.  I suppose you could also give `foo` the ability to flashback the database and just flashback to a savepoint where `foo` is an empty schema (assuming you intend to always re-create foo identically).

Comment: What do you mean with "in any regular DBMS"? What do you think a "regular DBMS" is? Can you do what you describe in say DB2, Apache Derby, SQL Anywhere, Informix, Firebird, Teradata or Ingres?

Comment: _"without disconnecting"_ is probably a very ... hem ... heavy requirement here. FWIW, when experimenting with Oracle with my students, I install Oracle in a VM image, and each student use its own copy-on-write clone of the image. In case of someone messing with her sample DB, I only have to delete its COW file, and let her start with a fresh one. It's only a matters of seconds. If the file-system of the host running Oracle has a snapshot feature, this is an other good option if you're the only one experimenting with the DB.